# How can I create a process that starts other processes in c#?

Tags: c#, process, parent-child

I would like to create a process that has no purpose but running other processes. (Which will act as his child processes) 
The child processes are "real" application like Notepad++, Adobe Photoshop, etc.

What I am trying to achieve is the ability to hold both processes, child and parent, as objects (System.Diagnostics) while having the flexibility of executing and killing whichever child process I choose to.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Show what you've tried and how it failed..

Comment: Since all processes that I execute are actually child processes of my application, what I am currently doing is                                           
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();                                                This way I am holding my apps process and any Process I run is its child process. This is not good enough as I need to be able to kill and re-run the parent process.

Comment: @ItamarLevy Why would you want to kill the process if its just running notepad or whatever?

Comment: Depending on the apps you spawn and how you spawn them you'd already have the process info..... it sounds like a design issue

Comment: I am writing a test that checks relationship of different processes, execution times and other metrics. The processes themselves or what they do is not relevant, the only thing that is relevant is how they behave after the application under test is injecting its code into them. It would be really hard to describe the whole architecture of what I am doing so you'll just have to trust me that I need to hold and control both processes :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a console application which will wait on user input with Console.Readline() for some command like "start proc", "kill" etc. This console application will be able to spawn your other processes and restarted if needed. You also can start this console app automatically with task scheduler.